# WooCommerce - Updating Product through API / HTTP Requests

Tags: woocommerce

I am attempting to update WooCommerce products through notifications sent by a third party application. I have read the documentation on doing this and it seems easy enough, but it looks like the only way to use the API to update a product is by Product ID.  Unfortunately, these are/were created incrementally while uploading the rather large product catalog into WooCommerce.

While making the .csv's and uploading to WooCommerce, we set the SKU's to be the same ID that the products have in the third-party software (book ISBN's).  So I am able to send that number (the number that corresponds with SKU in WC) with the HTTP request, but that does not allow me to perform the product update.

It seems to me, the best way to accomplish this integration would be to change the product ID's of all my products in WooCommerce to be the same as this unique number that is currently the SKU. It doesn't appear as though this is possible to do in the dashboard or user interface, so I imagine I'll have to do it on a database level.

Does anyone know what tables will need to be modified or if there is a way to do this in the dashboard? Maybe even a tweak to my HTTP request to the API that will allow me to update by SKU?

Answer (score 0):

Modifiy the Product IDs in the database directly is not a good choices.
This action is required to do every time when creating new products.

The most simplest and safe appoach is creating a new API,
which purpose for searching the product ID by SKU.

Here is a part of sample code.

```
function get_product_by_sku( $sku ) {
  global $wpdb;

  $product_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $sku ) );

  if ( $product_id ) return new WC_Product( $product_id );

  return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure this would help me in my current situation, unless I'm confused.  My third party application will be generating an http request on an action (such as a change in inventory quantities or a change in product pricing for example) and this will be sent to WooCommerce.  The only relevant information I can send along to match the product will be the SKU number that I mentioned.  Which is why I thought changing the ID would be the best option overall.  It seems to me that in the future, when creating new products with .csv's, I can manually set the ID to match this number.